# How To connect to the same WordPress database with different database user

Tags: database, mysql, wpdb

I have created a trigger on the posts table. but I want this trigger to be executed if the user connected to the database is x user.

I have tried to connect to the WordPress database with x user. it's working but the object wpdb contains null values in the posts,users, prefix and the other settings I were got from the default database connection with the WordPress database user.

code I used to connect with x user:

`$wpdb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);`

part of the `$wpdb` object :

```
  public 'comments' => null
  public 'commentmeta' => null
  public 'links' => null
  public 'options' => null
  public 'postmeta' => null
  public 'posts' => null
  public 'terms' => null
  public 'term_relationships' => null
  public 'term_taxonomy' => null
  public 'termmeta' => null
  public 'usermeta' => null
  public 'users' => null
  public 'blogs' => null
  public 'blog_versions' => null
  public 'registration_log' => null
  public 'signups' => null
  public 'site' => null
  public 'sitecategories' => null
  public 'sitemeta' => null
  public 'field_types' =>
```

So how to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is to call a function that will initialize the wpdb object properties. which is wp_set_wpdb_vars.

After you instantiate the wpdb object call that function.

```
$wpdb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
//Set the database table prefix and the format specifiers for database
wp_set_wpdb_vars();
```

Comment: In case of multisite this won't work as expected those properties  public 'comments' => null
  public 'commentmeta' => null
  public 'links' => null
will still null
  public 'options' => null
  public 'postmeta' => null
  public 'posts' = =>